# robot_localization

Tags: ros, navigation, roslauch, position, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use robot_localization package to stimate the position of my robot. First I am going to explain what I have.

Sensors:

IMU publishing sensor_msgs::Imu publishing in /imu_rectificada topic.
The IMU frame is ENU, 0 degrees when Y is in Norht and Z is up. I will fill the covariance once the node is working.

```
---
header: 
  seq: 191036
  stamp: 
    secs: 1434547057
    nsecs: 229000000
  frame_id: /imu
orientation: 
  x: -0.628702991434
  y: -0.315484655538
  z: 0.321512012361
  w: 0.633902097503
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.0138241518289
  y: -0.0111814923584
  z: 0.0322032161057
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.0442927330732
  y: -9.97963142395
  z: 0.102352119982
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

Wheel odometry publishing nav_msgs::Odometry in /odom topic.
It starts at 0 position.

```
---
header: 
  seq: 110736
  stamp: 
    secs: 1434546465
    nsecs: 469210289
  frame_id: /odom
child_frame_id: /base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 276.840007856
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.1
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
---
```

tf:

I publish the transform */odom -> /base_link* only with the information of odometry, so it doesnt have any global information. I cloud change this with the information of the imu, but actually im not interested in global positioning.

Here my first question, where should I set the transform for the IMU, I am trying with a transform */base_link -> /imu* where imu_frame is just base_link_frame but with the rotation reported from the IMU.

**Q1**: Is it good the transform I am publishing with the odometry? Where should I set the transform for the IMU?

My launch file is:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ukf_localization_node" name="ukf_localization" clear_params="true">

      <!-- My odometry publish at this frequency -->
      <param name="frequency" value="10"/>
      <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.15"/>
      <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>

      <param name="map_frame" value="/map"/>
      <param name="odom_frame" value="/odom"/>
      <param name="base_link_frame" value="/base_link"/>
      <param name="world_frame" value="/odom"/>

      <param name="odom0" value="/odom"/>
      <param name="imu0" value="/imu_rectificada"/>

      <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                      false, false, flase,
                                      true,  true, false,
                                      false, false, true,
                                      false, false, false]</rosparam>

      <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                     true,  true,  true,
                                     false, false, false,
                                     true,  true,  true,
                                     true,  true,  true]</rosparam>

      <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
      <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

      <!-- I want the realative position to my initial position-->
      <param name="odom0_relative" value="true"/>
      <param name="imu0_relative" value="true"/>

      <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>

      <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>

      <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="5"/>
      <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="1"/>

    </node>
</launch>
```

**Q2**: With all this I am getting an error message:

```
[FATAL] [1434542899.231523445]: Could not read sensor update configuration for topic odom0 (type: 7, expected: 7). Error was type error
```

I don't know what I'm missing, but I have tried simulating the publishers, i have used rosbags and the hardware, and it throw always the same error. It looks like the tipe of the message its not the correct, but I am using the types from the documentation.

Thanks for every answer that could help me, and sorry if my english is not very good.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks you very much for the quick response.

I have changed all this and now I only publish the transform */base_link -> /imu*, there is not error but robot_localization is not working, there is not tf or odometry messages. With before configuration im getting an advice in */diagnostic* topic:

```
  - 
    level: 2
    name: ukf_localization: Filter diagnostic updater
    message: Erroneous data or settings detected for a robot_localization state estimation node.
    hardware_id: none
    values: 
      - 
        key: Z_configuration
        value: Neither Z nor its velocity is being measured. This will result in unbounded error growth and erratic filter behavior.
  -
```

And I have added to odom0 the z velocity component in simulation, and I have changed the parameters in the way that z_velocity is read from odom0. Now the advice has disappeared but robot_localization is still not working, diagnostic topic say : "The robot_localization state estimation node appears to be functioning properly."

PD: I have checked if the nodes are conected by the right topics and they are.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have it running, thanks you.

Last thing, it is not necessary, but I would like to integrate the linear accelerations, when I set the parameter of acceleration to true the stimated position start to fly. This happen even if the parameter "imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" is true.

---

**UPDATE 3**

Hello another time,

I tried to use "robot_localization" in the real robot, and the estimation is not correct. I have tried a lot of configurations. I am going to upload my bags and my lunch file.
This first [bag](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kk9v175n9058hjo/terreno_exterior.bag?dl=0) file is just the sensors measures. Then I use an [intermediate node](https://www.dropbox.com/s/omkqisxeuqh6ga4/topic_pipe.cpp?dl=0) and I get this [bag](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5mzefnfmget3kz/terreno_exterior_conv.bag?dl=0) file. I am using this [launch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v28o8eezcpdmdzo/ukf_relative32.launch?dl=0) with some different configurations and I cannot do it work.

Thank you very much for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211549/robot_localization/) by [manuzagra](https://answers.ros.org/users/22704/manuzagra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-06-18**:
So entering this:

rostopic echo /odometry/filtered

...produces nothing? You can try turning on debug mode and *very* briefly run the node, then kill it and look at the debug output. Look for "failed" in the debug file. I suspect transforms.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-07-08**:
When you say the estimation is "not correct," in what way is it not correct? Are you saying that everything works in simulation, but not on a real robot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answers:

1. *I publish the transform /odom -> /base_link only with the information of odometry, so it doesnt have any global information. I cloud change this with the information of the imu, but actually im not interested in global positioning.*

Don't do that. `robot_localization` (`ekf_localization_node` or `ukf_localization_node`) will publish the *odom*->*base_link* transform for you.

*Here my first question, where should I set the transform for the IMU, I am trying with a transform /base_link -> /imu where imu_frame is just base_link_frame but with the rotation reported from the IMU.*

Just use a static transform. You don't need to constantly update the *base_link*->*imu* transform. If your IMU is really mounted at the center of your robot, just use the tf2 (or tf) `static_transform_publisher` and give it a transform of all zeros.

2. You mis-spelled "false" in your odom0 configuration for yaw. You have:

   ```
   <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   false, false, flase,
                                   true,  true, false,
                                   false, false, true,
                                   false, false, false]</rosparam>
   ```

You want:

```
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    true,  true, false,
                                    false, false, true,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>
```

**EDIT in response to update:**

If no output is being produced, then see my comment above about turning on debug mode. Right now, I am actually suspecting an issue with the transforms. You have forward slashes in the `frame_ids` in your messages, and you also put them in the configuration for `ukf_localization_node`. This would normally be correct. However, `robot_localization` uses `tf2`, and [we strip all forward slashes from the frame_ids](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration#Removal_of_support_for_tf_prefix) to be compliant with it. In other words, you should do two things

1. Remove the forward slashes from the `frame_id`s in your messages.
2. (Optional, but you should do it anyway) Remove the forward slashes from the `frame_id`s in your `ukf_localization_node` launch file.

By the way, if you're only fusing velocities (like you are for *odom0*), then you don't need to turn on `relative` mode. That's only for fusing absolute position or orientation data.

**EDIT in response to update 2:**

Are you sure your IMU is outputting linear accelerations correctly? See [this](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/Preparing%20Your%20Sensor%20Data#IMU) page. For the sample IMU message you posted above, was your IMU resting flat on a table in its neutral orientation? If so, your acceleration data is wrong. It should read **+**9.81 m/s^2 for Z when resting flat on a surface in its neutral orientation. If you roll it +90 degrees, it should read **+**9.81 m/s^2 for Y. If you pitch it +90 degrees (front end down), it should read **-**9.81 m/s^2 for X.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manuzagra](https://answers.ros.org/users/22704/manuzagra/) on 2015-06-25**:
I am not sure if this should be here or in a upload of the question...

my IMU is rotated, it isn't in his neutral orientation, I am using a static transform to model this